# Downscaling Video With FFMPEG - Setting Max Width and Height

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm currently trying to use FFMPEG to scale down my video sources from various resolution down to a max width of 854 and a max height of 480. I want to scale the aspect ratio properly with a modulus/divder min of 2.

Currently this is what I got:
scale=-2:'min(ih\,480)'

This is for the height part only, but still need to figure out how to do the width part and to keep the -2 divider enabled for both. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `scale=w='if(gt(dar,854/480),min(854,iw*sar),2*trunc(iw*sar*oh/ih/2))':h='if(gt(dar,854/480),2*trunc(ih*ow/iw/sar/2),min(480,ih))'`

Comment: Two quick questions. Whats the diff between SAR and DAR, and which does this preserve?
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: SAR is the sample aspect ratio and relates to the individual pixel. DAR is the display aspect ratio and concerns the full displayed frame. This preserves the latter. You may wish to add `setsar=1` after the scale for safety's sake.

Comment: Great. Will setsar=1 allow for the -2 setting to work or will it overwrite it?

Comment: The scale takes care of the mod 2 requirement. `setsar` has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Alright so I tried it and it gives me this error via the console. 

` Invalid size 'if(gt(dar,854/480)' [AVFilterGraph @ 0x3ea5f80] Error initializing filter 'scale' with args 'w=if(gt(dar,854/480):flags=bicubic'`
I did backspace all the commas so that shouldn't be an issue. Using it in a php script. 

`-vf hqdn3d=1.5:1.5:6:6,scale=w="if(gt(dar\,854/480),min(854\,iw*sar)\,2*trunc(iw*sar*oh/ih/2))":h="if(gt(dar,854/480)\,2*trunc(ih*ow/iw/sar/2)\,min(480\,ih))":flags=bicubic'`
Any ideas?

Comment: Try my filter on the command line as-is, so you can check whether escaping is the issue.

Comment: I had to \ space all the commas and it ran in the command line but it does now work. I setsar=1 before the scale code and after the denoiser.. Shows the same result: 

 854x374 [SAR 119680:119987 DAR 640:281] Is that what it should show? Thanks again for the help!

Edit: My bad. Now set after and working great :) Thanks again!

Comment: `setsar` has to be after the scale, as mentioned in my comment.

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm.